# Creating Tables With PHP Using PDFLib

Tags: php, database, pdflib

I was wondering if there was a good source on how to build tables using the PDFLib for PHP. I am planning to populate a PDF Document with a Database Table (well a few that I join together to create a new view) and I wanted to make it a PDF document for the web. I've been searching all over and I find plenty of information on PDFLib except how to create a table with it.

I've checked out the PDFLib commands on PHP.net and also can't quite get a clear grasp of what's needed.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with PDF generation a few times in the past, and generally find it to be a huge pain in the neck.

PDFLib's documentation http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-8.0.2-tutorial.pdf starts explaining what you're looking for in section 8.2, page 193. You'll be creating multi-line flows. The code there looks intimidating, but take some time to work through it, it's pretty close to what you'll end up using.

I may be able to find some code later, but I forget what library I was using. For now a few tips:

- Work it out on paper, just like their marked up examples. Where you want things to start, end, and such.
- Use clear variable names to store those offsets. Not constants!
- Find good extreme examples to test with while developing. Developing with text like "test" to find out later you need to support "I am the very model of the modern major general" may throw off your entire flow, and require you to start from scratch.
- Some libraries "support" HTML embeds, including HTML tables. This siren song is sweet, but will lead you into the razor sharp rocks. Every library I've used supports them a little bit, but then you run into a wall where you can't get the next little tweak without dropping tables and reverting to native functions. They've been a huge waste of time to play with, one and all.

**update**
I've found my most recent code iteration, we used the library from http://www.tcpdf.org. It worked, mostly. I dealt with a lot of inconsistencies in where the cursor was left after writing multiple lines of text to a page. I ended up ripping out anything that used their multi-line code and writing my own. That done it got pretty easy to work with.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks. I am reading through this now. Hopefully you (or I) can find some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Table handling in PDFlib is made extremely difficult. Tables work, but in cases where you have multiple tables in top of each other and want the below one tables to be always at a certain distance of upper table's bottom line or want to use nested tables, you are in trouble. These like behaviors can be made, but the code is complicated. WHY pdflib team didn't take usage behaviour of html tables, where they have worked well two centuries.

Because html tables are easy to use, one good method is to use [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to generate pdf from html. PhantomJS uses webkit for page rendering and supports html5+css3+svg+canvas. And in addition to pdf, it can output png, jpeg and gif.

Here is an example of using phantomJS to generate PDF-invoices:
http://we-love-php.blogspot.fi/2012/12/create-pdf-invoices-with-html5-and-phantomjs.html